# Law of total probability - aplication

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients, poisson-distribution

I am trying to understand thesolution of the following example:

Each cuatomer who enters John's clothing store will purchase a suit with probability p. If the number of customers entering the store is a poisson random variable with mean $\mu$, what is the probability that John sells k suits?

Solution:

$P(X=k) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty P(X=k|N=n) P(N=n) =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}e^{-\mu}\frac{\mu^n}{n!}
$

So far i could understand. Bue the rest of the solution i can not understand. Ould someone be able to break it down for me ?

$ = e^{-\mu}\frac{(\mu p)^{n}}{k!} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\mu(1-p))^{n-k}}{(n-k)!} = e^{- \mu p} \frac{(\mu p)^k}{k!},k>0
$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $P(X=k\mid N=n)=0$ if $n<k$ so that we can start the summation with $n=k$ instead of $n=0$.

Let's abbreviate $q:=1-p$

$$\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\binom{n}kp^kq^{n-k}e^{-\mu}\frac{\mu^n}{n!}=e^{-\mu}\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\binom{n}k(\mu p)^k(\mu q)^{n-k}\frac1{n!}=e^{-\mu}\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\frac{(\mu p)^k(\mu q)^{n-k}}{k!(n-k)!}=$$$$e^{-\mu}\frac{(\mu p)^k}{k!}\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\frac{(\mu q)^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}=e^{-\mu}\frac{(\mu p)^k}{k!}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\mu q)^{n}}{n!}=e^{-\mu}\frac{(\mu p)^k}{k!}e^{\mu q}=e^{-\mu p}\frac{(\mu p)^k}{k!}$$

Comment: I am still struggeling with some parts, where does the $\frac{1}{n!}$ aka. How comes that $\mu$ Can be distributed into the brackets ? Also the last sum is $n=0$ instead of $n=k$, is that correct?

Comment: $\binom{n}{k}\frac1{n!}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\frac1{n!}=\frac1{k!(n-k)!}$. Secondly $p^kq^{n-k}\mu^n=p^kq^{n-k}\mu^{k}\mu^{n-k}=(p\mu)^k(q\mu)^{n-k}$. And $\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}a_{n-k}=a_0+a_1+\cdots=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ applied to $a_n=\frac{(\mu q)^n}{n!}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{n}{k}p^k (1-p)^{n-k} e^{- \mu} \frac{\mu^n}{n!} = e^{-\mu} p^k \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} (1-p)^{n-k}\frac{\mu^n}{n!} = e^{-\mu}\frac{(p \mu)^k}{k!} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\mu (1-p))^{n-k}}{(n-k)!} = e^{-\mu}\frac{(p \mu)^k}{k!} e^{\mu (1-p)} = e^{-\mu p} \frac{(p \mu)^k}{k!}$$